# bundler install getting "i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rails-i18n

How can I correct this "i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3" I get when I run "bundler install"?

Background:  Need to use ruby 1.8.7 on dreamhost, so have targeted Rails v3.2 for this.

Command Line

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:weekends Greg$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-12-22 patchlevel 375) [i686-darwin14.1.0]

Gregs-MacBook-Pro:weekends Greg$ bundler -v
Bundler version 1.9.2

Gregs-MacBook-Pro:weekends Greg$ bundler install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies............
Using rake 10.4.2
Gem::InstallError: i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
An error occurred while installing i18n (0.7.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install i18n -v '0.7.0'` succeeds before bundling.
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:weekends Greg$ 

Gregs-MacBook-Pro:weekends Greg$ gem install i18n -v '0.7.0'
ERROR:  Error installing i18n:
    i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

Gem File

```
gem 'rails', '3.2' # Dreamhost is Ruby 1.8.7. Rails 3.2 requires at least Ruby 1.8.7
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'google-api-client', :require => 'google/api_client'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'rest-client'
```

Comment: Try specifying the ruby version you're using in your `Gemfile`, like this: `ruby "1.8.7"`. btw, why you tagged this question with `ruby-on-rails-4` if you're installing `rails 3`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to downgrade I18n's version to [0.6.11](https://rubygems.org/gems/i18n/versions/0.6.11), because that seems to be the latest version that does not require Ruby 1.9.3. To do so add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'i18n', '0.6.11'
```

and try to run `bundle install` again.

Furthermore, I suggest upgrading your Ruby and Rails versions. They are both outdated. At least you could try to run Rails 3.2 with a version of Ruby that allows the new syntax. Otherwise, you will face this kind of problems with many other gems too and - more important - you will not be able to install all the security fixes there were released during the last years.

Comment: I'll try this - background is I need to ruby 1.8.7 on dreamhost (unless I upgrade to a VPS, costs more), so have targeted Rails v3.2 for this

Comment: I think it is bad decision to trade the low cost for a VPS against the risk of well known security issues in outdated software stacks. You might want to consider hosting on Heroku then, they have a free plan.

Comment: good point @spickermann - plus I'm still having trouble trying to replicate this older stack too...