# Why Rails still needs Ruby => 1.9.3 after upgrade to 2.2.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am re-installing Ruby (last version 1.9.1) to version 2.2.6. I am doing this because I was trying to install the Rails gem, but when I did `gem install rails` I got an error saying:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

So I re-installed Ruby but now to version 2.2.6, everything went good but when, again, trying to install the Rails gem I still get the same error.

When I write `ruby -v` in console it returns:

```
ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x86_64-linux]
```

I really **wouldn't like to reboot** the server for it to take effect, is it the only way?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What is your `gem -v`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bundler install getting "i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451038/bundler-install-getting-i18n-requires-ruby-version-1-9-3)

Comment: @EliSadoff it returns: 2.4.5.2

Comment: @Ritwick tried that already, but thanks.

Comment: @mkmnstr which OS do we talk about, and what do you use to manage Ruby installation? RVM or native installation, or something else? I mean, I can see Linux, but it doesn't tell me if there's any specific distro.

Comment: Im sorry, I am running CentOs 6.5. Thanks @mutantkeyboard

Comment: it depends on how you are installing ruby. Are you using a version manager?

Comment: @mkmnstr I will assume we talk about DigtalOcean instance. I would try `gem update --system` first, and then try `gem update rails -f`

Comment: Are you using rvm/rbenv?

Comment: What does `gem environment | grep "RUBY VERSION:"` give you?

Comment: @maxpleaner not using a version manager.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard tried and still the same. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Andrés (tocayo xD)  not using rvm.

Comment: @EliSadoff it gives me:   - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.10 (2016-04-01 patchlevel 492) [x86_64-linux]